# Why does my first svg path setting back to original state in Safari only?

Tags: css, animation, svg, path

I have a stroke animation for two paths in a svg. Basically a class is added via js when the svg enters the viewport and adds the class "draw".

It works perfect in all browsers except safari. My safari versions are all 13+ so I think it has nothing to do with the prefixes. I am totally confused because the second path stays at its' end state. The first one sets back after the animation happend.

That is my CSS code:

```
        .drawn-connection-line {
            .arrow-stroke {
                stroke-dasharray: 444px;
                stroke-dashoffset: 444px;
            }
            .arrowhead {
                stroke-dasharray: 66px;
                stroke-dashoffset: 66px;
            }    
        }
        .drawn-connection-line.draw {
            .arrow-stroke {
                animation-name: draw-connection-line-body;
                animation-duration: 0.5s;
                animation-direction: normal;
                -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3,.03,.75,.96);
            }
            .arrowhead {
                animation-name: draw-connection-line-head;
                animation-duration: 0.4s;
                animation-delay: 0.5s;
                animation-direction: normal;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.29,.38,.48,1); 
            }
        } 
        @keyframes draw-connection-line-body {
            from {
                stroke-dashoffset: 444px;
            }
            to {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
            }
        }
        @keyframes draw-connection-line-head {
            from {
                stroke-dashoffset: 66px;
            }
            to {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
            }
        }
```

The "arrow-stroke" and "arrowhead" are the classes for the paths inside the svg. "arrow-stroke" is the first on.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Try getting rid of the webkit prefixed line: it shouldn't matter, but Safari may have a bug there

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't change anything.